# Googlebot is not reading dynamic content

Tags: adsense

Website is fully dynamic.

meta tags, opengraph tags and contents are created dynamicially on webpages.
I might be doing something wrong. Please guide me to get approved for GOOGLE ADSENSE Program.

*Google Adsense gave reason "**Insufficient content**" for this*

Answer (score 1):

I think the only real answer is to implement some kind of partial caching. If needed content is not in the source code of your pages, it won't be indexed.
What exactly do you mean by "fully dynamic" and what parts do you want to be indexed?